# Camel not publishing to RabbitMQ queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq

I have a simple route defined in a routeContext in  Camel (this route will be used in multiple routes).

```
    <route id="sendToRabbitQueue">
        <from uri="direct:sendToQueue" />
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <setHeader headerName="rabbitmq.ROUTING_KEY">
            <constant>my.routing.key</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="ref:genericRabbitEndpoint"/>
    </route>
```

And I have an endpoint (defined in an endpoints file)

```
    <endpoint id="genericRabbitEndpoint" uri="rabbitmq://${rabbitmq.host}:${rabbitmq.port}/${rabbitmq.exchange.name}">
        <camel:property key="autoDelete" value="false" />
        <camel:property key="connectionFactory" value="#rabbitConnectionFactory" />
    </endpoint>
```

Yes - I have seen the http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html page - that's where I got the idea to set the header on the exchange. However no message is being published on the queue. I'm clearly overlooking something and  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Airomega - How did you setup your endpoints file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this seems like a bit of a gotcha and the answer relates to part of the route I didn't include in the question because I didn't think it was relevant.

The route starts at a RabbitMQ endpoint (not included above). As a result the exchange has some RabbitMQ headers set when it arrives:

- `rabbitmq.ROUTING_KEY`
- `rabbitmq.EXCHANGE_NAME`
- `rabbitmq.DELIVERY_TAG`

These headers are used across the life of the route and appear to override the values when I try to publish at a different RabbitMQ endpoint. The way I've fixed is by introducing a bean which strips the headers out. Not ideal behaviour in my opinion...

```
public void stripRabbitHeaders(@Headers Map headers)
{
    headers.remove("rabbitmq.ROUTING_KEY");
    headers.remove("rabbitmq.DELIVERY_TAG");
    headers.remove("rabbitmq.EXCHANGE_NAME");
}
```

Comment: BTW: you can easily remove headers from within your route with `removeHeaders(String pattern, String... excludePatterns)`